# cannot get footer to stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, web, formatting, footer

I'm new to web design/development and I'm getting hung up on this problem. I'm practicing my skills by creating a sample webpage, with the following format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZEiD.png

---

The two columns have the .col class and the whole page is wrapped in a .wrapper class.

Now, I've seen that to get the footer to stick to the bottom, I need to do the following:

```
html, body, .wrapper, .col
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, this isn't changing anything.  I'm trying not to post all of my css as it will take up a bunch of space, but if it's needed I will do that.

Can someone have any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: do you want footer to stick at the bottom of the page on case even the content is very limited on your `wrapper` class.

Comment: you want footer like this. http://jsbin.com/gewakele/1/edit

Comment: let me know if my Demo helps you.

Comment: Understanding "fixed" positioning is the first thing, but it also has a bunch of caveats. In your screenshot it doesn't take into account if the content isn't the full height of the screen etc. Here is where I ended up after years of dealing with this.  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ziGbE

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply css to the footer like this.

```
<style>
#footer{
...
...
bottom:0px;
position:fixed;
...
}
</style>

...
...
<body>
<div id="footer"> content.. </div>
</body>
```